# npm - error in main, module not found - new laravel (8) app

Tags: php, laravel, npm, laravel-8, npm-run

Complete Laravel newbie here but I've googled for the past hour with no luck.

I've installed Laravel via composer (everything was working with the default set up) but I wanted to use bootstrap so I've installed npm, followed this guide [here](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-8-install-bootstrap-example-tutorialexample.html) but when I run `npm run dev` I get an error:

```
 Error in main 
 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in
'C:\xampp\htdocs...'
```

*Edited to include the rest of the error

```
webpack 5.3.1 compiled with 1 error in 69 ms
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-29T14_19_55_826Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "npm run development"
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-29T14_19_55_857Z-debug.log
```

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Providing the rest of the error message would be useful. On another note, if your goal is to just have bootstrap, you don't necessarily need to install it with npm, using bootstraps cdn works fine as well.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add it to the original question